# Deactivating an active character

Tags: catcodes, active-characters

How do I deactivate an active character?  The following works without the activizations in the preamble, but not with them, in spite of my attempt to reset the catcode of `:` to `12`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`:=\active \def:{\,\string:}
\catcode`!=\active \def!{\,\string!}

\begin{document}

Tom went on whitewashing---paid no attention to the steamboat. Ben stared
a moment and then said: `\emph{Hi-Yi! You're} up a stump, ain't you!'
\catcode`\:=12
\label{not:to:be:typeset}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\label{not\string:to\string:be\string:typeset}`

Comment: Better: use `babel` features.

Comment: The label is stored in a the aux-file and read back at \begin{document}, so you should pay attention at the catcode values there too.

Comment: @egreg, which babel features?

Comment: @egreg, I suppose one could use l3regex to replace all occurrences of : inside \label with \string:, unless there is a better way.

Comment: @Toothrot Shorthands are automatically neutralized in `\label`